# python urlopen error [Errno 10060]

Tags: python, urlopen

I am trying to run the following code,

```
for parname in parss:
    data = {'action': 'listp', 'parish': parname}
    data = urllib.urlencode(data)
    req = urllib2.Request('http://www.irishancestors.ie/search/townlands/ded_index.php', data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

but i get the error below few minutes after the code gets executed

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

This is my proxy settings.

[image]

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: For me the connection works out. Firewall, Anti-Virus or something which could block?

Comment: Michael, the code runs few loops before giving the error. I get the error even when firewall turned off , no antivirus :(

Comment: How many iterations? I could execute 100 without a problem. What are you doing with the response objects? Do you have other connections? They could be blocking your IP because of many accesses in very short time.

Comment: around 60 itreations it works fine. I am capturing data in the html tables in to my data frame. Is there any work around to prevent that kind of a blocking? I dont have other simultaneous connections. would time.sleep(secs) work?

Comment: time.sleep(60) did the job. thank you so much Michael :)

Comment: This should be way to long. Try a few seconds.

Comment: ok.. thanks again Michael :)

Comment: No problem! I transfered the results of our discussion into an answer. Feel free to accept it, *if* it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, executing large numbers of requests in very short time can lead to the server, especially web-servers, to block your connection attempts.

This is a common counter measure to automated attacks on the web.
Depending on the server, waiting very short amounts of time between requests should solve your problem.

You could also use a more dynamic approach. First, execute as much requests as possible with no waits in between. If a request takes significantly longer than usual it is most likely a timeout and you have to wait. At this point, you cancel your request, wait and try again. If the subsequent try also results in a timeout you double the waiting time. With this procedure, called *adaptive backoff*, you should be (hopefully) able to access the data you want with minimal overhead.

Answer (score 0):

in terminal type "xhost +"
should solve problem temporarily

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).